# Excel: Every other date on X-axis displayed fromthe end

Tags: excel, date, graph

I have a set of dates and matching numbers in excel, one number for every month in 2013. I need to display these numbers with the dae on the X-axis in a simple line graph. I am mainly intereseted in the number for the last month but also the historical numbers.

It is to crowded on the X-axis to show every single month so I only show every other month. This is easily done by right clicking the axis etc.

Now, since the last month is the most important one I would like to show that month (2013-12) and every other month backwards.

The axis should look something like this:

2013-02, 2013-04, 2013-06, 2013-08, 2013-10, 2013-12

But no matter how I change in excel I end up with this:

2013-01, 2013-03, 2013-05, 2013-07, 2013-09, 2013-11

Since the last month (december) is the most important one I would say it is logical to display that month.

The only way I can get it working is by dropping the first observation which I don't want to do.

Any suggestions how I can et this working in excel?

Answer (score 0):

You have a "fencepost problem". You want to display 12 values, but if you want to display every second one, either you take all the odd numbers (in which case december is hidden) or all the even ones (which hides january)

If you're okay with hiding january, then add a dummy month at the beginning of your series, and give it the value:

```
=na()
```

Excel will allot it space but will not give it a point on the graph.

Alternately, if your axis is too crowded, turn the label text sideways or put the year 2013 in the title and only put the months on the x axis (1, 2, 3, ..., 12)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I tried it but without any success, maybe I am doing it wrong.

I tried adding a =na() at the beginnign (above jan 2013). 
Also tried adding =na() over the numbers (every month has a number).
Tried the two above combined.
Tried changing jan 2013 to =na().

But it still doesn't work. The only way I can get this working is if I remove january but then then number is removed from the graph and it would be much nicer if I wouldn't have to do this.

Comment: I have a feeling I wasn't clear: There has to be a month, e.g. Dec. 2012, and then the number is =na().